# RxJS Interval without delay

Tags: javascript, typescript, rxjs, rxjs5, reactive-extensions-js

The following code emits an `int` after `5000ms` and then another in every `5000ms` later:

```
let evens = Observable.interval(5000)
     .map(i => {
          return i * 2;
      });

 evens.subscribe((i) => {
      console.log(i);
 });
```

Is it possible to do this, but have the first result immediately (`0ms`), and then wait `5000m`s between subsequent results?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You can use [`timer()`](http://reactivex.io/rxjs/class/es6/Observable.js~Observable.html#static-method-timer) where the first parameter is the initial delay:

```
timer(0, 5000);
```

Or if you want the first item to be emitted immediately you can also use the [`startWith()`](http://reactivex.io/rxjs/class/es6/Observable.js~Observable.html#instance-method-startWith) operator.

Jan 2019: Updated for RxJS 6